# How to get the last executed result of a SQL statement in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I executed a SQL query which was a very resource consuming one. It took about 19 minutes to produce result. But, after having the result, I executed another SQL without saving the result data to some file. Thus, the result is gone and I have to re-execute the query to get the result again.

Is there a way (or does SQL Developer saves last query result as history) to retrieve the last result without executing the SQL again?

Thank you.